# Modifying contents of container with iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I have a vector and I am modifying it's contents by using iterators. If some condition is met, I need to modify the contents of the next element in the vector. I thought that the following would work:

```
*(it + 1)++;
```

It made sense to me, since I have been able to tell loops to stop one short of the end using the condition `it != vec.end() - 1`. It doesn't seem to have any effect on the contents of the container though, so I settled on the following:

```
++it;
*it += 1;
--it;
```

It's three lines to the previous one, and I consider it a hack. Is there a better way to do this? What's the trick that I'm missing to be able to increment the next element in the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean:

```
(*(it + 1))++;
```

or `++*(it + 1).` This is a precedence issue, similar to how `*p++` increments the pointer, not the pointed-to value.

Alternatively, for a random-access iterator you can write `it[1]++;` or `++it[1];`.

It's generally preferred to use pre-increment unless you need the properties of post-increment. This is because post-increment returns by value, so if the object has an expensive copy process but you don't actually need the copy, then you wasted time making the copy.

Comment: You won the speed race.  :)  Consider also that `++*(it + 1)` works and is more concise/clear.

Comment: In this case the objects are just integers, but I'll keep the pre/post increment in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a pointer and incrementing it.
Dereference the iterator and then increment.

```
(*(it + 1))++;
```

or

```
*(it + 1) += 1;
```